# what is the difference between '==' and '==='?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Not really relative to any type of code, just in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`===` is the *identical* operator; it returns `true` when *both the value and the type* of the two operands are the same. `==` is the *equal* operator; it does not check types, just values.

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 6):

usually `===` also represents equality of type.

so:

```
   1 == "1" //true
   1 === "1" //false
```

Comment: I just upvoted this and a pink unicorn appeared and put a balloon on it.. Am I hallucinating?

Comment: @Nick , its an april fools thing for all upvotes ^_^

Answer (score 1):

=== compares the value **as well as type** of variable
== doesn't compare type